# select distinct elements with count of not matching ids

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I ma not sure whether my problem will be solved with query alone or i will need to take help of scripting language to do this

```
select customer_ref, full_name, email, phone from contacts where customer_ref = '123';

  contact_id  |  customer_ref  |   full_name    | email          |     phone      
  ------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--------------
  1           |   123          | Jhon           | jhon@xyz.com   | 1234567890
  2           |   123          | Jhon Doe       | jhon@xyz.com   | 1234567890
  3           |   123          | JD             | jhon@gmail.com | 1234567890
  4           |   123          | Jhon           | jhon@xyz.com   | 1234567890
  5           |   123          | Jhon           | jhon@xyz.com   | no phone given
  6           |   123          | Jhon           | jhon@xyz.com   | 1234567890
```

and what I want is to group together matching information like

```
contact_ids|customer_ref  |   full_name    | email          |     phone      | count
-----------+--------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------
[1, 4, 6]  |   123        | Jhon           | jhon@xyz.com   | 1234567890     | 3
[2]        |   123        | Jhon Doe       | jhon@xyz.com   | 1234567890     | 1
[4]        |   123        | JD             | jhon@gmail.com | 1234567890     | 1
[5]        |   123        | Jhon           | jhon@xyz.com   | no phone given | 1
```

currently i am doing this stuff of grouping with the help of ruby like

```
 contacts = Contact.select('full_name, email, phone').where(:customer_ref => '123')
 contacts.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |k,v| k[v] += 1; k }.map {|k,v| {:contact =>k.with_indifferent_access, :count => v }} if contacts.present?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_agg()` grouping by all columns except of `contact_id`:

```
select 
    array_agg(contact_id) contact_ids, 
    customer_ref, full_name, email, phone,
    count(*)
from contacts
group by 2, 3, 4, 5
order by 1

 contact_ids | customer_ref | full_name |     email      |     phone      | count 
-------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+-------
 {1,4,6}     |          123 | Jhon      | jhon@xyz.com   | 1234567890     |     3
 {2}         |          123 | Jhon Doe  | jhon@xyz.com   | 1234567890     |     1
 {3}         |          123 | JD        | jhon@gmail.com | 1234567890     |     1
 {5}         |          123 | Jhon      | jhon@xyz.com   | no phone given |     1
(4 rows)
```